# python - extract first element from tuple

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have an array of tuple,and trying to extract the first element, but its giving some random output.

```
import operator

c_details=[('id', 'integer', None, 32, 0), ('name', 'character varying', 10, None, None)]
for mapping in c_details:
        source_name=map(operator.itemgetter(0), mapping)
        print(source_name)

OUTPUT:
<map object at 0x01959358>
<map object at 0x01959148>
```

Then I tried this.

```
source_name=list(map(operator.itemgetter(0), mapping))

output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/rbhuv/Desktop/code/bqshift.py", line 26, in <module>
    source_name=list(map(operator.itemgetter(0), mapping))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Can someone help me to solve this? (its python 3.8)

Comment: Why not just use list comprehension, ``[x[0] for x in c_details]`` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first element of each tuple is simply:

```
mapping[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not giving you some random output but tells you that `map(...)` returns a [**generator**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map).
You could use a simple list comprehension instead:

```
c_details = [('id', 'integer', None, 32, 0), ('name', 'character varying', 10, None, None)]
lst = [tpl[0] for tpl in c_details]
print(lst)
```

Which yields

```
['id', 'name']
```

Please go ahead and read something about generators (e.g. [**here**](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/)), they are quite mighty and useful in `Python`.

Answer (score 0):

how about you change your code like this:

```
import operator

c_details=[('id', 'integer', None, 32, 0), ('name', 'character varying', 10, None, None)]
for mapping in c_details:
        print(mapping[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just de couple each element from tuple separately by assigning its value to new variable just like below :

```
c_details=[('id', 'integer', None, 32, 0), ('name', 'character varying', 10, None, None)]

for entry in c_details:
  ele1, ele2, ele3, ele4, ele5 = entry
  print(ele1)
```